# Wordpress, validate for required shortcode attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have a code that validate attributes during render of shortcode.
But, I need to implement validation for required attributes of shortcode when administrator of the wordpress editing the post(Before save). Is it really hard to make it on wordpress?

Comment: What I would probably do is detect you're making a post and enable some validation logic on the post data, either though do_shortcode or some other means and fire off a validation response. (Re adding it as a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Thank you for your pointing out direction. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no easy way to achieve it. Need to make a lot of staff:

**1. Catch post update event:**

```
add_action( 'pre_post_update', [ $this, 'validate_post_short_code_attributes' ], 10, 2 );
```

**2. Parse your shortcode in the post and validate**

```
public function validate_post_short_code_attributes( $post_id, $post_data ) {

        # If this is just a revision, don't do anything.
        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
        preg_match_all( '/(\[viatel\s([\S\s]+?)])/', $post_data['post_content'], $matches );

        if ( array_key_exists( 2, $matches ) ) {
            $attrs = shortcode_parse_atts( $matches[2][0] );
            try {
                $this->validate_required_attributes( $attrs );
            } catch ( LogicException $exception ) {
                # Add a notification
                update_option(
                    'viatel_notifications',
                    json_encode( [ 'error', $exception->getMessage() ] )
                );
                # And redirect
                header( 'Location: ' . get_edit_post_link( $post_id, 'redirect' ) );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

**3. Implement hacks with notifications and options**

[More information from this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63384/how-to-validate-custom-fields-in-custom-post-type)

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'viatel_notice' );
```

---

```
function viatel_notice() {
    $notifications = get_option( 'viatel_notifications' );
    if ( ! empty( $notifications ) ) {
        $notifications = json_decode( $notifications, true );
        #notifications[0] = (string) Type of notification: error, updated or update-nag
        #notifications[1] = (string) Message
        #notifications[2] = (boolean) is_dismissible?
        switch ( $notifications[0] ) {
            case 'error': # red
            case 'updated': # green
            case 'update-nag': # ?
                $class = $notifications[0];
                break;
            default:
                # Defaults to error just in case
                $class = 'error';
                break;
        }

        $is_dismissible = '';
        if ( isset( $notifications[2] ) && $notifications[2] == true ) {
            $is_dismissible = 'is_dismissible';
        }
        echo '<div class="' . $class . ' notice ' . $is_dismissible . '">';
        echo '<p>' . $notifications[1] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        # Let's reset the notification
        update_option( 'viatel_notifications', false );
    }
}
```